# Not sure how to handle insert method's return type

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAlll( product:List<Product>):List<Product>
}
```

```
 override fun getFactoriProduct(): Observable<List<Product>> {
        return Observable.create { emitter ->
            api.getProductRemote()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    if (it != null) {
                        emitter.onNext(db.productDao().insertAlll(it))
                        Timber.e("request->$it")
                    }
                }, {
                    emitter.onNext(db.productDao().getProduct())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    Timber.e("ErrorRequest->$it")
                })
        }
    }
```

activity.kt

```
 fun init() {
        mainViewmodel.getProduct().subscribe {
            val adapter = ProductAdapter(it)
            RecyclerView2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)
            RecyclerView2.adapter = adapter
            adapter.update(it)
        }.addTo(this.CompositeDisposable)
```

how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract java.util.List insertAlll(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Comment: Make it a ``Single<Long>`` or ``Maybe<Long>`` for insert one entry and ``Single<List<Long>>`` or ``Maybe<List<Long>>`` for bulk insertion. Also you can read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) for more clarity

Comment: I want to put in the database of my product list, which I encountered with this error, can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

As per [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert)

A method annotated with the @Insert annotation can return:

> - long for single insert operation
> - long[] or Long[] or List for multiple insert operations
> - void if you don't care about the inserted id(s)

Answer (score -1):

Generally when you use rxjava with room what you do is observe the changes of the database, so that whenever you insert or delete a data from database you get a new Flowable or observable of the updated data.

so firstly include this in your app gradle file

**app/build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha06'
```

This will help you to directly return a stream of data from  room.

Now in your Daos you can make the following changes

**Dao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface Dao{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAlll(product:List<Product>):Single<List<Int>>

    @Query("Select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
    fun getAll():Flowable<List<Product>> // return a flowable here because this will be triggered whenever your data changes
}
```

Now in your view model get the data

**ViewModel.kt**

```
  val data = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>;    

  db.dao().getAll() // will fetch a new data after every insertion or change
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(
        { data.postValue(it)  },
        { e -> e.printstacktrace() }
      ))

   // This is just to insert the  list of produts
   db.dao().insertAll(listProduct)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
               {// Do nothing   },
               { e -> e.printstacktrace() }
             ))
```

Now in your Activity you can update your UI by observing data

**Activity.kt**

```
viewModel.data.observe(this, Observer { 
   //update your recycler view adapter here    
 })
```